# How to pack a lot of constructor parameters into separate object in python?

Tags: python, constructor

For example this piece of code creates a label with some content
which can be text, bitmap etc

```py
label1 = tk.Label(text="Hello", font=("Arial",32,"bold"), bg="grey", fg="red",width=200,height=200) #and so on...
```

I cannot really refactor how `tk.Label` constructor handle things nor change it.
In my case I would like to configure text / font in a separate object.
All styling in another object and width/height in again another object.

Like this:

```py
size_config = ElementSize(width=200,height=200)
styling_config = Style(bg="red",fg="blue")
text_config = ...

# then create label with this objects
```

And this is just an example. I very often get frustrated from how badly python libraries uses constructors and I don't know what to do with this over 9000 parameters that have no structure in them at all.

Maybe there is something wrong with me?
There is a way to hide all of this stuff in some sort of scoped objects and then map them to all of this nightmare in constructors?

Comment: Is the intention to reuse these config objects in many labels/widgets?

Comment: Are you looking for the [Introduce Parameter Object](https://refactoring.guru/introduce-parameter-object) refactoring?

Comment: I cannot refactor tk.Label. If I could I would done it already. Yes, I seek for more reusability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `**kwargs` unpacking.

```
label_args = dict(
    text="Hello",
    font=("Arial",32,"bold"),
    bg="grey",
    fg="red",
    width=200,
    height=200,
) #and so on...

label1 = tk.Label(**label_args)
```

If you want to apply static typing to these things, you can define `TypedDict`s for each function signature.

Comment: Oh! This looks a lot better! And now I even could create some wrapper for parts of parameters and then combine their dict representation! This will do a thing! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use your own function?

```
from inspect import getfullargspec


class Label:
    def __init__(self, text, font, bg, fg, width, height):
        self.text = text
        self.font = font
        self.bg = bg
        self.fg = fg
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        print("created a label")


class ElementSize:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height


class Background:
    def __init__(self, bg):
        self.bg = bg


def map_arguments(argument_sources, cls, **kwargs):
    arguments = dict()
    for argument_source in argument_sources:
        argument_source_signature = getfullargspec(argument_source.__init__).args
        for arg in argument_source_signature:
            if arg == "self":
                continue
            arguments[arg] = argument_source.__getattribute__(arg)
    arguments.update(kwargs)
    return cls(**arguments)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    label = map_arguments([ElementSize(2, 4), Background("grey")], Label, fg="red", text="Hello",
                          font=("Arial", 32, "bold"))
```